# How will i add call invitation (signaling) in zego cloud?

Tags: flutter, dart, call, zegocloud

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zego_uikit_prebuilt_call/zego_uikit_prebuilt_call.dart';

class VideoCallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoCallScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<VideoCallScreen> createState() => _VideoCallScreenState();
}

class _VideoCallScreenState extends State<VideoCallScreen> {
  String? userId = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  String? userName = DateTime.now().toString();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCall(
      appID: '',
      appSign:
          '',
      userID: userId!,
      userName: userName!,
      callID: 'demo_call_id_for_testing',
      config: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVideoCall(),
    );
  }
}

Chat_screen:
Widget appBar() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => ViewProfileScreen(user: widget.user),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Expanded(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: APIs.getUserInfo(widget.user),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final data = snapshot.data?.docs;
            final list =
                data?.map((e) => ChatUser.fromJson(e.data())).toList() ?? [];

            return Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black54)),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(mq.height * .03),
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    width: mq.height * .05,
                    height: mq.height * .05,
                    imageUrl:
                        list.isNotEmpty ? list[0].image : widget.user.image,
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        const CircleAvatar(child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person)),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        list.isNotEmpty ? list[0].name : widget.user.name,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 2),
                      Text(
                        list.isNotEmpty
                            ? list[0].isOnline
                                ? 'Online'
                                : MyDateUtil.getLastActiveTime(
                                    context: context,
                                    lastActive: list[0].lastActive)
                            : MyDateUtil.getLastActiveTime(
                                context: context,
                                lastActive: widget.user.lastActive),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => const AudioCallScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.phone,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => const VideoCallScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


``
```

When i press  the audio and video call icon it is connecting with the user whom i want to reach, but as for now it is connecting when the user touches the video and audio icon button. I need it should behave when i touch the video or audio call icon button it should gives signal to the user whom i'm trying to reach for video call and the signal should be two buttons Answer and Decline. same like WhatsApp UI Logic.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your ZegoCloud init function at the launch of your app or after the user logs in. So you could have something like:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    initZego();
    super.initState();
  }




void initZego() async{
   await ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallInvitationService().init(
      appID: appId //input your AppID,
      appSign: appSign //input your AppSign,
      userID: "currentUserId",  
      userName: "currentUserName",
      notifyWhenAppRunningInBackgroundOrQuit: true,
      androidNotificationConfig: ZegoAndroidNotificationConfig(
        channelID: "ZegoUIKit",
        channelName: "Call Notifications",
        sound: "notification",
        icon: "notification_icon",
      ),
      iOSNotificationConfig: ZegoIOSNotificationConfig(
        isSandboxEnvironment: false,
        systemCallingIconName: 'CallKitIcon',
      ),
      plugins: [ZegoUIKitSignalingPlugin()],
      controller: callController,
      requireConfig: (ZegoCallInvitationData data) {
        final config = (data.invitees.length > 1)
            ? ZegoCallType.videoCall == data.type
                ? ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.groupVideoCall()
                : ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.groupVoiceCall()
            : ZegoCallType.videoCall == data.type
                ? ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVideoCall()
                : ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVoiceCall();

        config.avatarBuilder = customAvatarBuilder;

        /// support minimizing, show minimizing button
        config.topMenuBarConfig.isVisible = true;
        config.topMenuBarConfig.buttons
            .insert(0, ZegoMenuBarButtonName.minimizingButton);

        return config;
      },
    );
  }
```

This will initialise the user to your ZegoCloud service, allowing ZegoCloud to send invitations to the user device by their userID

Comment: Can you kindly guide me according to my code, I feel some difficulties. still it shows an error.

Comment: You are running ZegoCloud init on the call page ie. the page the user is directed to when they click your call button. This is why ZegoCloud is not able to send an invitation to the user until they click the call button.

If you call the init function beforehand (suggestively when you launch your app), then the user will be registered to your ZegoCloud and will be able to receive call invitations even before they click the call button.

Comment: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCall(
      appID: '',
      appSign:
          '',
      userID: userId!,
      userName: userName!,
      callID: 'demo_call_id_for_testing',
      config: ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallConfig.oneOnOneVideoCall(),
    );

This widget from your code is what initialises this user. Try calling the ZegoUIKitPrebuiltCallInvitationService().init() function  without having to navigate to your VideoCallScreen() page.